# Can I authenticate a smart card from another company on my domain?

Tags: domain, active-directory, smartcard

I have a smart card that was issued by my company. I have AD setup at my house, and I login remotely via terminal server/client. I would like to be able to log in via smart card only.

Is it possible to setup my domain to authenticate my companies smart card?

Answer (score 0):

You would need an interdomain trust configured for the login on your companies domain to allow you to log into your domain.

[TechNet Article: Trust Relationships](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc977993.aspx)

Comment: Just curious, are you sure that is not reversed? On my domain at home, shouldn't I add my companies domain as a trusted domain?

Comment: The type of trust relationship would most likely be one way, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961481.aspx.  Its still a type of interdomain trust.